# How to scale a mesh without destroying the UV Map

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, scale

I was as you can see below, I placed a bump and a normal texture on a cylinder with UV mapping, but I need to scale the cylinder up to make it longer.
[image: cylinders]2]]

But it then ruins the UV mapping,
So I'll ask, Is there a way to scale a mesh without ruining the uv\texture?
The texture I used was...

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2VGh.png)

Comment: Adjust the scaling in the UV Image Editor

Comment: I don't get why texture becomes that dark when mesh is scaled however I don't think you want to scale the mesh. Add Array modifier and texture will be tiled. Afaik there isn't built-in way to do exactly what you asked

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy option to scale without it affecting the uv map: While in edit mode, go to 'Active Tool and Workspace Settings' > And activate 'Correct Face Attributes'.[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you scale your object on Z axis in 3D viewport, you must be careful to adjust your geometry in UV Image Editor because it don't have Z axis and you have to adjust on both X and Y axis.

You must scale the UV Unwrapped Geometry like this:

### See images and scale accordingly.

*Default Mesh with texture.*
[image]
*Scaled on Z Axis with Texture*
[image]

Can you see I have scaled the UV Map differently in both images.
Shortcuts are same for scaling in UV Image Editor that is <kbd>S</kbd>

> There are many free tutorials out their who covers Texture Mapping.

All the Best.

Comment: I don't think I understood what you meant, I asked if there's a way to simultaneously  scale them both and that didn't seem like you did, please correct me if I'm wrong